# Scala, IntelliJ and Gradle dependencies

Tags: apache-spark, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to change my project dependencies to Scala 2.11 as I am having troubles with 2.12. My current plugin installation is 2.12. How can I change everything to 2.11?

My project is built on Gradle and this is my build.gradle class:

```
 group 'ics5114'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

idea {
    project {
        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = '1.8'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-graphx_2.11', version: '2.3.0'
}


jar {
    zip64 true
    archiveName = "music-graph-spark.jar"
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.sparkTutorial.sparkSql.StackOverFlowSurvey'
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

Comment: You could manually configure dependencies version: [group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-compiler', version: "2.11.8"],
        [group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: "2.11.8"],

Comment: Do you need to point to the Scala 2.11 manually as well? When I added these dependencies, IntelliJ has Setup Scala SDK. When I click it I only have scala-sdk-2.12.6. Why is 2.11 not showing as well?